# Using git cli, how can I get the date and time of the latest commit of a repository that I have access to but have not cloned?

Tags: git, date, datetime, commit

I need to check the datetime of the latest commit of a repo I will not have cloned, but do have access to via ssh keys.

EDIT: just realized my question was imprecise and is not the question I needed to ask. Closing this and will ask again.

Comment: I know the branch - I'm trying to minimize data transfer so I only want to clone if I'm going to rebuild

Comment: I realize that I could pull updates, but that's not what I want to do

Comment: You could do a shallow clone to just get the latest to help reduce clone size/time.

Comment: That's a good idea

Comment: Is the repo hosted on Github so that you have access to their api?

Comment: Yes it is on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

Clone and try a `git log --all --date-order -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd`. Note that there are many date formats, see https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats.

If you don't want to clone the entire repo, try using --depth flag on the clone to limit the history you are pulling down.